# How to store operations in tensorflow using a loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following problem where I would like to code

```
 W_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape = [hidden_size1, hidden_size2], stddev = 0.1), name = "weights_hidden", trainable = True)
 b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, hidden_size2]), name="bias", trainable = True)

 hidden_relu_0 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(BN1[0], W_hidden)+b)
 hidden_relu_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(BN1[1], W_hidden)+b)
```

and so on where BN1 has some size, say n. I tried to use numpy array, list, Tensorarray and tf.concat but I did not manage to make it work.

Ideally it would be something equivalent to

```
 tensor_list = []
 for index in range(0,window_size):
     hidden_relu = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(BN1[index], W_hidden)+b)
     tensor_list.append(hidden_relu)
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: How exactly is `BN1` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the loop as you are using and after the loop, you can convert your list to a tensor using [tf.convert_to_tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) like

```
tf.convert_to_tensor(tensor_list, dtype=tf.float32)
```